# Spotify API: how to extract JSON information from different levels into one datFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, spotify

How to extract from this JSON object "artist name", "popularity" and "uri" into a dataframe?

```
{
  "tracks" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=karma+police&offset=0&limit=20&type=track&market=BR",
    "items" : [ {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn",
        "id" : "7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn",
        "images" : [ {
          "height" : 640,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/f89c1ecdd0cc5a23d5ad7303d4ae231d197dde98",
          "width" : 640
        }, {
          "height" : 300,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/1b898f0b8e3ce499d0fc629a1918c144d982e475",
          "width" : 300
        }, {
          "height" : 64,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/faf295a70a6531826a8c25d33aad7d2cd9c75c7a",
          "width" : 64
        } ],
        "name" : "OK Computer",
        "type" : "album",
        "uri" : "spotify:album:7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb",
        "id" : "4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb",
        "name" : "Radiohead",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
      } ]
```

I can access same level information, but having trouble getting sublevels of the JSON object.

Comment: Hi @Adelita, can you show us what you've tried before that hasn't worked? That will help us help you - we can see where you need to be guided for the answer.  See if this answer is any help [navigating json table in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909678/navigating-json-table-in-python)

Comment: I have tried d1 = pd.DataFrame(obj['tracks']['items'])[['name', 'popularity']] which gives me part of the info I need, but cannot get artist's name there as the path to follow would be ['tracks']['items'][0]['artists']. So how to combine in the dataFrame to obtain both?

Comment: I gave a pretty detailed answer below - should get you going! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested json can be confusing and hard to access sometimes, but pandas makes it pretty easy to handle in a few steps.

I decided to work from the spotify [tracks API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-tracks) here, based on what I think you are using. The data sample is at the bottom of this post.

TL;DR: Use `json_normalize()`:

```
# get access to tracks and put it in a nice variable
# use json_normalize to flatten it into a nice df 
# rename columns 
# normalize the 'artists' column in the df that contains nested json 
# rename columns 
# concatenate the original df and the artists df 
# you can remove the original 'artists' / 'track_artists' field as it is no longer 
# necessary, the values have been flattened out into their own columns.
```

After looking at your data structure and what you're trying to accomplish, I think this is a job for [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)!

Using pandas's `json_normalize()` will somewhat flatten your nested json, and get you most of the way there.

What's tricky, however, is that for every track, the value in the `'artists'` key holds a list that holds a dictionary of results, instead of holding one value or another dictionary as a value, which `json_normalize()` can handle easily.

Take note that `tracks['album'][0][artists]` holds `key:value` pairs with keys that are the same name as in the 'album' dictionary.

It looks like everything you want is going to be inside of tracks, so let's make a variable for easy access:

```
tracks = data['tracks]
```

json_normalize() to the rescue:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(tracks)
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 28 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                        --------------  ----- 
 0   artists                       3 non-null      object
 1   available_markets             3 non-null      object
 2   disc_number                   3 non-null      int64 
 3   duration_ms                   3 non-null      int64 
 4   explicit                      3 non-null      bool  
 5   href                          3 non-null      object
 6   id                            3 non-null      object
 7   is_local                      3 non-null      bool  
 8   name                          3 non-null      object
 9   popularity                    3 non-null      int64 
 10  preview_url                   3 non-null      object
 11  track_number                  3 non-null      int64 
 12  type                          3 non-null      object
 13  uri                           3 non-null      object
 14  album.album_type              3 non-null      object
 15  album.artists                 3 non-null      object
 16  album.available_markets       3 non-null      object
 17  album.external_urls.spotify   3 non-null      object
 18  album.href                    3 non-null      object
 19  album.id                      3 non-null      object
 20  album.images                  3 non-null      object
 21  album.name                    3 non-null      object
 22  album.release_date            3 non-null      object
 23  album.release_date_precision  3 non-null      object
 24  album.type                    3 non-null      object
 25  album.uri                     3 non-null      object
 26  external_ids.isrc             3 non-null      object
 27  external_urls.spotify         3 non-null      object
```

If you check your dataframe at this point, you will see most values were neatly flattened into their own rows, but since we want artist info as well, we have to go a few steps further.

```
# change column names because you know there are dupes 

# this will create a properly formatted dictionary for renaming columns 
keys = {k:f'track_{k}' for k in df.keys()[:14]}

# rename columns 
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: keys.pop(x) if x in keys.keys() else x)
```

Your df will now have its keys prepended with 'track_' so you know the are part of the main track dict.

The 'artists' values are still not flat, so let's flatten those.  A special case since each dictionary is inside a list.

```
# normalize artist column and cat the resulting columns into a dataframe 
# we use a list comprehension to get to the dict to use for json_normalize()

df_artists = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(y)) for x in df.track_artists for y in x], ignore_index=True)

# make a dict of new column names prepended with 'artist_' so we know it came from the 'artist' nested dict
kys = {k:f'artist_{k}' for k in df_artists.keys()}

# rename the columns 
df_artists = df_artists.rename(columns=lambda x: kys.pop(x) if x in kys.keys() else x)

Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                        --------------  ----- 
 0   artist_href                   3 non-null      object
 1   artist_id                     3 non-null      object
 2   artist_name                   3 non-null      object
 3   artist_type                   3 non-null      object
 4   artist_uri                    3 non-null      object
 5   artist_external_urls.spotify  3 non-null      object
```

We have renamed the columns so that we know if they are related to the track or the artist and so we don't have any duplicate name collisions that make the data harder to find and sort later.

Now we put everything together into one dataframe:

```
flat_df = pd.concat([df, df_artists], axis=1)


 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                        --------------  ----- 
 0   track_artists                 3 non-null      object
 1   track_available_markets       3 non-null      object
 2   track_disc_number             3 non-null      int64 
 3   track_duration_ms             3 non-null      int64 
 4   track_explicit                3 non-null      bool  
 5   track_href                    3 non-null      object
 6   track_id                      3 non-null      object
 7   track_is_local                3 non-null      bool  
 8   track_name                    3 non-null      object
 9   track_popularity              3 non-null      int64 
 10  track_preview_url             3 non-null      object
 11  track_track_number            3 non-null      int64 
 12  track_type                    3 non-null      object
 13  track_uri                     3 non-null      object
 14  album.album_type              3 non-null      object
 15  album.artists                 3 non-null      object
 16  album.available_markets       3 non-null      object
 17  album.external_urls.spotify   3 non-null      object
 18  album.href                    3 non-null      object
 19  album.id                      3 non-null      object
 20  album.images                  3 non-null      object
 21  album.name                    3 non-null      object
 22  album.release_date            3 non-null      object
 23  album.release_date_precision  3 non-null      object
 24  album.type                    3 non-null      object
 25  album.uri                     3 non-null      object
 26  external_ids.isrc             3 non-null      object
 27  external_urls.spotify         3 non-null      object
 28  artist_href                   3 non-null      object
 29  artist_id                     3 non-null      object
 30  artist_name                   3 non-null      object
 31  artist_type                   3 non-null      object
 32  artist_uri                    3 non-null      object
 33  artist_external_urls.spotify  3 non-null      object
```

So if at the end, all you want is a dataframe with just the 3 columns you mentioned, it would be something like:

```
final_df = flat_df[['artist_name', 'track_popularity', 'artist_uri']]
```

Here is the data object below:

```
data = {
    "tracks": [
        {
            "album": {
                "album_type": "single",
                "artists": [
                    {
                        "external_urls": {
                            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                        },
                        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                        "id": "6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                        "name": "Carly Rae Jepsen",
                        "type": "artist",
                        "uri": "spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                    }
                ],
                "available_markets": [
                    "AD",
                    "AR",
                    "AT",
                    "AU",
                    "BE",
                    "BG",
                    "BO",
                    "BR",
                    "CA",
                    "CH",
                    "CL",
                    "CO",
                    "CR",
                    "CY",
                    "CZ",
                    "DE",
                    "DK",
                    "DO",
                    "EC",
                    "EE",
                    "ES",
                    "FI",
                    "FR",
                    "GB",
                    "GR",
                    "GT",
                    "HK",
                    "HN",
                    "HU",
                    "ID",
                    "IE",
                    "IL",
                    "IS",
                    "IT",
                    "JP",
                    "LI",
                    "LT",
                    "LU",
                    "LV",
                    "MC",
                    "MT",
                    "MX",
                    "MY",
                    "NI",
                    "NL",
                    "NO",
                    "NZ",
                    "PA",
                    "PE",
                    "PH",
                    "PL",
                    "PT",
                    "PY",
                    "RO",
                    "SE",
                    "SG",
                    "SK",
                    "SV",
                    "TH",
                    "TR",
                    "TW",
                    "US",
                    "UY",
                    "VN",
                    "ZA"
                ],
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/0tGPJ0bkWOUmH7MEOR77qc"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0tGPJ0bkWOUmH7MEOR77qc",
                "id": "0tGPJ0bkWOUmH7MEOR77qc",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "height": 640,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/966ade7a8c43b72faa53822b74a899c675aaafee",
                        "width": 640
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 300,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/107819f5dc557d5d0a4b216781c6ec1b2f3c5ab2",
                        "width": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 64,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/5a73a056d0af707b4119a883d87285feda543fbb",
                        "width": 64
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Cut To The Feeling",
                "release_date": "2017-05-26",
                "release_date_precision": "day",
                "type": "album",
                "uri": "spotify:album:0tGPJ0bkWOUmH7MEOR77qc"
            },
            "artists": [
                {
                    "external_urls": {
                        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                    },
                    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                    "id": "6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                    "name": "Carly Rae Jepsen",
                    "type": "artist",
                    "uri": "spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                }
            ],
            "available_markets": [
                "AD",
                "AR",
                "AT",
                "AU",
                "BE",
                "BG",
                "BO",
                "BR",
                "CA",
                "CH",
                "CL",
                "CO",
                "CR",
                "CY",
                "CZ",
                "DE",
                "DK",
                "DO",
                "EC",
                "EE",
                "ES",
                "FI",
                "FR",
                "GB",
                "GR",
                "GT",
                "HK",
                "HN",
                "HU",
                "ID",
                "IE",
                "IL",
                "IS",
                "IT",
                "JP",
                "LI",
                "LT",
                "LU",
                "LV",
                "MC",
                "MT",
                "MX",
                "MY",
                "NI",
                "NL",
                "NO",
                "NZ",
                "PA",
                "PE",
                "PH",
                "PL",
                "PT",
                "PY",
                "RO",
                "SE",
                "SG",
                "SK",
                "SV",
                "TH",
                "TR",
                "TW",
                "US",
                "UY",
                "VN",
                "ZA"
            ],
            "disc_number": 1,
            "duration_ms": 207959,
            "explicit": False,
            "external_ids": {
                "isrc": "USUM71703861"
            },
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/11dFghVXANMlKmJXsNCbNl"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/11dFghVXANMlKmJXsNCbNl",
            "id": "11dFghVXANMlKmJXsNCbNl",
            "is_local": False,
            "name": "Cut To The Feeling",
            "popularity": 63,
            "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/3eb16018c2a700240e9dfb8817b6f2d041f15eb1?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86",
            "track_number": 1,
            "type": "track",
            "uri": "spotify:track:11dFghVXANMlKmJXsNCbNl"
        },
        {
            "album": {
                "album_type": "album",
                "artists": [
                    {
                        "external_urls": {
                            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                        },
                        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                        "id": "6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                        "name": "Carly Rae Jepsen",
                        "type": "artist",
                        "uri": "spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                    }
                ],
                "available_markets": [
                    "AD",
                    "AR",
                    "AT",
                    "AU",
                    "BE",
                    "BG",
                    "BO",
                    "BR",
                    "CA",
                    "CH",
                    "CL",
                    "CO",
                    "CR",
                    "CY",
                    "CZ",
                    "DE",
                    "DK",
                    "DO",
                    "EC",
                    "EE",
                    "ES",
                    "FI",
                    "FR",
                    "GB",
                    "GR",
                    "GT",
                    "HK",
                    "HN",
                    "HU",
                    "ID",
                    "IE",
                    "IL",
                    "IS",
                    "IT",
                    "JP",
                    "LI",
                    "LT",
                    "LU",
                    "LV",
                    "MC",
                    "MT",
                    "MX",
                    "MY",
                    "NI",
                    "NL",
                    "NO",
                    "NZ",
                    "PA",
                    "PE",
                    "PH",
                    "PL",
                    "PT",
                    "PY",
                    "RO",
                    "SE",
                    "SG",
                    "SK",
                    "SV",
                    "TH",
                    "TR",
                    "TW",
                    "US",
                    "UY",
                    "VN",
                    "ZA"
                ],
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/6SSSF9Y6MiPdQoxqBptrR2"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6SSSF9Y6MiPdQoxqBptrR2",
                "id": "6SSSF9Y6MiPdQoxqBptrR2",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "height": 640,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/2fb20bf4c1fb29b503bfc21516ff4b1a334b6372",
                        "width": 640
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 300,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/a7b076ed5aa0746a21bc71ab7d2b6ed80dd3ebfe",
                        "width": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 64,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/b1d4c7643cf17c06b967b50623d7d93725b31de5",
                        "width": 64
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Kiss",
                "release_date": "2012-01-01",
                "release_date_precision": "day",
                "type": "album",
                "uri": "spotify:album:6SSSF9Y6MiPdQoxqBptrR2"
            },
            "artists": [
                {
                    "external_urls": {
                        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                    },
                    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                    "id": "6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                    "name": "Carly Rae Jepsen",
                    "type": "artist",
                    "uri": "spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                }
            ],
            "available_markets": [
                "AD",
                "AR",
                "AT",
                "AU",
                "BE",
                "BG",
                "BO",
                "BR",
                "CA",
                "CH",
                "CL",
                "CO",
                "CR",
                "CY",
                "CZ",
                "DE",
                "DK",
                "DO",
                "EC",
                "EE",
                "ES",
                "FI",
                "FR",
                "GB",
                "GR",
                "GT",
                "HK",
                "HN",
                "HU",
                "ID",
                "IE",
                "IL",
                "IS",
                "IT",
                "JP",
                "LI",
                "LT",
                "LU",
                "LV",
                "MC",
                "MT",
                "MX",
                "MY",
                "NI",
                "NL",
                "NO",
                "NZ",
                "PA",
                "PE",
                "PH",
                "PL",
                "PT",
                "PY",
                "RO",
                "SE",
                "SG",
                "SK",
                "SV",
                "TH",
                "TR",
                "TW",
                "US",
                "UY",
                "VN",
                "ZA"
            ],
            "disc_number": 1,
            "duration_ms": 193400,
            "explicit": False,
            "external_ids": {
                "isrc": "CAB391100615"
            },
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/20I6sIOMTCkB6w7ryavxtO"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/20I6sIOMTCkB6w7ryavxtO",
            "id": "20I6sIOMTCkB6w7ryavxtO",
            "is_local": False,
            "name": "Call Me Maybe",
            "popularity": 74,
            "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/335bede49342352cddd53cc83af582e2240303bb?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86",
            "track_number": 3,
            "type": "track",
            "uri": "spotify:track:20I6sIOMTCkB6w7ryavxtO"
        },
        {
            "album": {
                "album_type": "album",
                "artists": [
                    {
                        "external_urls": {
                            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                        },
                        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                        "id": "6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                        "name": "Carly Rae Jepsen",
                        "type": "artist",
                        "uri": "spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                    }
                ],
                "available_markets": [
                    "AD",
                    "AR",
                    "AT",
                    "AU",
                    "BE",
                    "BG",
                    "BO",
                    "BR",
                    "CA",
                    "CH",
                    "CL",
                    "CO",
                    "CR",
                    "CY",
                    "CZ",
                    "DE",
                    "DK",
                    "DO",
                    "EC",
                    "EE",
                    "ES",
                    "FI",
                    "FR",
                    "GB",
                    "GR",
                    "GT",
                    "HK",
                    "HN",
                    "HU",
                    "ID",
                    "IE",
                    "IL",
                    "IS",
                    "IT",
                    "JP",
                    "LI",
                    "LT",
                    "LU",
                    "LV",
                    "MC",
                    "MT",
                    "MX",
                    "MY",
                    "NI",
                    "NL",
                    "NO",
                    "NZ",
                    "PA",
                    "PE",
                    "PH",
                    "PL",
                    "PT",
                    "PY",
                    "RO",
                    "SE",
                    "SG",
                    "SK",
                    "SV",
                    "TH",
                    "TR",
                    "TW",
                    "US",
                    "UY",
                    "VN",
                    "ZA"
                ],
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/1DFixLWuPkv3KT3TnV35m3"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1DFixLWuPkv3KT3TnV35m3",
                "id": "1DFixLWuPkv3KT3TnV35m3",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "height": 640,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/3f65c5400c7f24541bfd48e60f646e6af4d6c666",
                        "width": 640
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 300,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ff347680d9e62ccc144926377d4769b02a1024dc",
                        "width": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "height": 64,
                        "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/c836e14a8ceca89e18012cab295f58ceeba72594",
                        "width": 64
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Emotion (Deluxe)",
                "release_date": "2015-09-18",
                "release_date_precision": "day",
                "type": "album",
                "uri": "spotify:album:1DFixLWuPkv3KT3TnV35m3"
            },
            "artists": [
                {
                    "external_urls": {
                        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                    },
                    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                    "id": "6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju",
                    "name": "Carly Rae Jepsen",
                    "type": "artist",
                    "uri": "spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju"
                }
            ],
            "available_markets": [
                "AD",
                "AR",
                "AT",
                "AU",
                "BE",
                "BG",
                "BO",
                "BR",
                "CA",
                "CH",
                "CL",
                "CO",
                "CR",
                "CY",
                "CZ",
                "DE",
                "DK",
                "DO",
                "EC",
                "EE",
                "ES",
                "FI",
                "FR",
                "GB",
                "GR",
                "GT",
                "HK",
                "HN",
                "HU",
                "ID",
                "IE",
                "IL",
                "IS",
                "IT",
                "JP",
                "LI",
                "LT",
                "LU",
                "LV",
                "MC",
                "MT",
                "MX",
                "MY",
                "NI",
                "NL",
                "NO",
                "NZ",
                "PA",
                "PE",
                "PH",
                "PL",
                "PT",
                "PY",
                "RO",
                "SE",
                "SG",
                "SK",
                "SV",
                "TH",
                "TR",
                "TW",
                "US",
                "UY",
                "VN",
                "ZA"
            ],
            "disc_number": 1,
            "duration_ms": 251319,
            "explicit": False,
            "external_ids": {
                "isrc": "USUM71507009"
            },
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr",
            "id": "7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr",
            "is_local": False,
            "name": "Run Away With Me",
            "popularity": 50,
            "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/3e05f5ed147ca075c7ae77c01f2cc0e14cfad78d?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86",
            "track_number": 1,
            "type": "track",
            "uri": "spotify:track:7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the problem correctly you can try not to use list structure, edit it like this

```
data = {
    "tracks": {
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=karma+police&offset=0&limit=20&type=track&market=BR",
        "items": {
            "album": {
                "album_type": "album",
                "available_markets": ["AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR",
                                      "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT",
                                      "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC",
                                      "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY",
                                      "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY"],
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn",
                "id": "7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn",
                "images": [{
                    "height": 640,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/f89c1ecdd0cc5a23d5ad7303d4ae231d197dde98",
                    "width": 640
                }, {
                    "height": 300,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/1b898f0b8e3ce499d0fc629a1918c144d982e475",
                    "width": 300
                }, {
                    "height": 64,
                    "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/faf295a70a6531826a8c25d33aad7d2cd9c75c7a",
                    "width": 64
                }],
                "name": "OK Computer",
                "type": "album",
                "uri": "spotify:album:7dxKtc08dYeRVHt3p9CZJn"
            },
            "artists": {
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb",
                "id": "4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb",
                "name": "Radiohead",
                "type": "artist",
                "uri": "spotify:artist:4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
            }}}}
```

then this example will give you "uri"

```
print(data["tracks"]["items"]["artists"]["uri"])
```

if it's not a json you can fix, you should do it like this as it contains list

```
print (data["tracks"]["items"][0]["artists"][0]["uri"])
```

In cases where there is more than one, you can get all the data with the loop

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I can get individually those results, but my question is how to print for instance uri, popularity and artist name in one go.